# multiple SockJs connections

Tags: sockjs

I am trying to create handler for SockJs connections which handle multiple users simultaneously like this:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandler snakeHandler() { return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(SnakeHandler.class); }
```

And with code on client side:

```
Game.socket = new SockJS('/snake/snake');

                Game.socket.onopen = function () {
                    Console.log('Info: WebSocket connection opened.');
                    Console.log('Info: Press an arrow key to begin.');
};
```

The problem is with next connection, not first. When I connect at first, I got single *WebSocketSession*. But all next, got 3 connections:
*WebSocketSession, XhrStreamingSockJsSession and PollingSockJsSession* and no messages "Info: WebSocket connection opened." in browser console, only first client gets it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution?